# Ansible: How to globally set PATH for solaris

Tags: path, solaris, environment, ansible

I am writing Ansible playbooks to setup and install our applications on Solaris servers.

The problem is that the (bash) scripts which I need to execute all assume that a certain directory lies on the PATH, namely `/data/bin` - which would normally not be a problem were it not for Ansible ignoring all the `.profile` and `.bashrc` config.

Now, I know that you can specify the environment for `shell` tasks via the `environment` flag, for example like this:

```
- shell: printenv
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/data/bin
```

This will properly path the `/data/bin` folder, and the `printenv` command will correctly display (or my bash scripts would correctly run).

**But.** There are two problems however:

- First of all it is very annoying to have to specify the environment over and over again. I know that you can define the environment in some playbook base file variable and the reference that, but you *still* have to set `environment: ...` on every single `shell` task.
- Secondly, the above example does not allow me to specify the path dynamically, e.g. as `PATH: $PATH:/data/bin` - because Ansible executes this in a way which does not resolve `$PATH`, thus the command fails catastrophically. So essentially this will override any other changes to `PATH`.

I am looking for a solution where

- the additional `PATH` entry should only be added **once**
- the additional `PATH` entry should not override entries added by other tasks

P.S. I found this nice explanation on [how to do this on Linux](https://coderwall.com/p/ynvi0q/updating-path-with-ansible-system-wide), but it makes use of `/etc/environment` which does not exist on Solaris. (And `/etc/profile` is once again ignored by Ansible.)

Answer (score 1):

try adding `-o SendEnv=PATH` to `ssh_args` in [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html). Requires that

- the shell in which you run ansible has /data/bin in PATH. Or however ansible allows you to modify the current/local PATH variable.
- remote machine has [AcceptEnv](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) set correctly.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help me. We call ansible playbooks from our dev machines which of course have a very different setup/os/path than the servers we are trying to manage. Still, might be useful to someone else...